# Why is my NSDateFormatter creating the wrong date?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create datefromstring.  However, the date is just wrong that is created.  Can anyone see anything wrong with my code?

this is the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm"];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *datePart = [txtView.text substringToIndex:16];
NSLog(@"datepart: '%@'", datePart);
NSDate *midDate = [format dateFromString:datePart];
NSLog(@"format middate: %@", [format stringFromDate:midDate]);
```

this is the output:

```
datepart: '04/29/2013 04:23'
format middate: 01/05/2013 04:23
```

It is certainly not January by any means - why is this so incorrect??

Thanks!
R

Comment: Try logging `midDate` before formatting it back to a string and see where it comes out

Comment: It comes out: 2013-01-05 09:39:00 +0000.  so it is in the datefromstring method, I guess.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Date Formatting Guide documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> [This example] uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

I've give the code sample a run using both YYYY and yyyy, and yyyy yields the correct result.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"];
[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *datePart = @"04/29/2013 04:23";
NSLog(@"datepart: '%@'", datePart);
NSDate *midDate = [format dateFromString:datePart];
NSLog(@"format middate: %@", [format stringFromDate:midDate]);
```

Prints out

```
2013-04-29 21:40:42.450 Untitled[95290:707] datepart: '04/29/2013 04:23'
2013-04-29 21:40:42.453 Untitled[95290:707] format middate: 04/29/2013 04:23
```

**Fun Fact!**

This was the cause of the Do Not Disturb bug Apple had at the start of 2013, they used YYYY instead of yyyy. [Some more info here.](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2013/jan/03/apple-do-not-disturb-bug-explained)

Comment: Oh jeez, I hate that mistake, so easy to get those two mixed up

Comment: Oh man! That is a good fun fact - at least Apple fooled themselves with that one!  Thanks so much - you saved the day!!